# custom Shipping woocommerce for multi vendor mp plugin

Tags: woocommerce

I have created a custom shipping method for my multi vendor marketplace plugin on woo commerce but the problem is that i want This shipping method to have settings like flat rate does. need help any help will be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful.
they have given the explaination for everything.
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098